# Dynamically creating objects using a for loop

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to Java and trying to create an application to help with my trading. I have a method to read a csv file that I input, which is table with x number of rows and 3 columns. It reads it as multidimensional String array (String[][]) Eg

Pair-----  Buy Price ---Sell Price
AUDUSD   0.9550  ---  0.9386
EURUSD    1.3333 --- 1.3050
GBPUSD   1.5705 --- 1.5550

(please excuse my formatting)

I have a constructor called ForexPair that looks like this:

```
public class ForexPair extends PriceWarning{

public String pairName;
public double buyPrice;
public double sellPrice;

public ForexPair(String pair, String buy, String sell) {
    pairName = pair;
    buyPrice = Double.valueOf(buy);
    sellPrice = Double.valueOf(sell);
}
```

My question is this: Can I use a 'for' loop to create an object for each row in my CSV file? I believe I can use an ArrayList for this. However I want the name of each object I create to be the Pair Name in the first column of my csv file. For example:

```
ForexPair AUDUSD = new ForexPair(pairNames[0], (myArray[0][1]),(myArray[0][2]));
```

But how do I create the object called AUDUSD using a for loop? So that each object has a different name?

Currently I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] myArray = getInputArray();
    String[] pairNames = new String[myArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < pairNames.length; i++){
        pairNames[i] = myArray[i][0];                   //Creates 1D String array with pair names.
        ForexPair pairNames[i] = new ForexPair(pairNames[i], (myArray[i][1]),(myArray[i][2]));
    }
}
```

Comment: pairNames is defined as a string array. You cannot redeclare it as a ForexPair in your loop. You need a list of ForexPair, to which you append new instances. "The name of each object" is confusing; you don't need to keep a reference to each object--they're in the list. *Edit* Oh, you meant a hash--I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable *names* are not relevant - they aren't even kept track of after your code is compiled. If you want to map names to objects you can instead place `ForexPair` instances in a `Map<String, ForexPair>`, i.e.

```
Map<String, ForexPair> map = new HashMap<String, ForexPair>();

...

// in the for-loop:
map.put(pairNames[i], new ForexPair(pairNames[i], myArray[i][1],myArray[i][2]));
```

Although this seems slightly redundant, as you already have the name as a field in each `ForexPair`, so you might want to consider removing this field and keeping track of the name only via the map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use a `HashMap`.
rough example:

```
HashMap<String, ForexPair> myMap = new HashMap<String, ForexPair>();
myMap.put("AUDUSD", new ForexPair(pairNames[0], (myArray[0][1]),(myArray[0][2])));
ForexPair pair = myMap.get("AUDUSD");
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

> Can I use a 'for' loop to create an object for each row in my CSV file?

Yes, that's possible:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourCsvFile));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     // do something with line.
}
```

2.

> But how do I create the object called AUDUSD using a for loop? So that each object has a different name?

I think your mixing up two different concepts: **name of variable** and **value of your variable called pair**
The value of your variable is the important point, while the name of your variable only provides code quality!

Answer (score 0):

```
            final TableLayout tview = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblGridStructure);
            final JSONArray JarraymenuItems = {item1,it3m1mwer,wer,ds};//your list of items
            for (int i = 0; i < JarraymenuItems.length(); i++) 
                        {
    ableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tview.addView(tr, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 45);
            T
            final TextView etprice = new TextView(this);
            etprice.setText("your text value wat u want to display");
tr.addView(etprice );
int count = tview.getChildCount();
                    if (count % 2 != 0)
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E3E3E3"));
            }
```